# Как починить поиск постов?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Мне нужно вытащить title с posts, но вместо этого страница не отображается(при использовании map(), без filter(), все работает

```
export const CardsEpisodes = () => {
  
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { posts } = useSelector((state) => state.posts);

  const isPostsLoading = posts.status === 'loading';
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPosts());
    dispatch(fetchTags());
    dispatch(fetchComments());
  }, []);

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('1');
  const [valuePos, setValuePos] = React.useState('1');

  const filtered = posts.items.filter(obj => {
    return obj.title.toLowerCase().includes(valuePos?.toLowerCase)
  })

    return (
      <>
      <input type='search'  className={styles.input} onChange={(event) => setValuePos(event.target.valuePos)}/>
      <TabContext value={value}>
      <TabPanel value="1"> 
        <Grid xs={8} item>
          {filtered.map(obj => 
            (
              <Post
                id={obj._id}
                title={obj.title}
                text={obj.text}
                user={obj.user}
                episode={obj.episode}
                imageUrl={obj.imageUrl ? `${'http://localhost:4444'}${obj.imageUrl}` : ''}
                audioUrl={obj.audioUrl ? `${'http://localhost:4444'}${obj.audioUrl}` : ''}
                tags={obj.tags}
              />
            ),
          )}
        </Grid>
        </TabPanel>
      </TabContext>
      </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Одна из возможных причин - в момент рендер не существует цепочка, которую вы проверяете `title.toLowerCase().includes(valuePos?.toLowerCase)` в функции filtered. На момент первоначального рендернинга, posts может быть null.

Comment: @SwaD спасибо за ответ, можете подсказать как сделать posts видимым для данной функции ?

Comment: Так он видит, только он null (выведете в консоль). Вам необходимо поставить проверку, например так `posts?.items?.filter`

Comment: @SwaD когда вывожу в консоль posts.items он выводит данные, значит он не может достать title , что предпринять?( проверку я ставил, результат аналогичный)

Comment: Могу только cosole.log() посоветовать... Без понимания структуры данных сложно дать объективный ответ. try catch еще могу посоветовать, что бы выводил данные, если ошибка произошла. Суть у вас одна - где то структура данных хромает...

Comment: @SwaD спасибо большое за попытки) , мне кажется дело в синтаксисе , нужно просто правильно передать объект

Comment: Да пожалуйста ) console.log творит чудеса!

Comment: @SwaD ахах, я добился выгрузки постов через filter, но теперь filter не работает, можете подсказать как реализовать здесь проверку   const filtered = posts?.items?.filter(obj => {
      return <Post 
        title={obj.title.toLowerCase().includes(valuePos?.toLowerCase)}
      />
  })

Comment: Так он и до этого толком не работал. Оформите новый вопрос, где приведите ваш код и ошибку, которую получаете

Comment: @SwaD до этого посты не выгружались, сейчас сделаю вопрос